# PHP DOM adding class by choosing a specific child

Tags: php, dom, children

I came across a problem and i can not find any solution online. So the problem is that i have no clue how to add a class to a specific child with PHP DOM. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="grid grid-flex gutters-horizontal">
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-flex gutters-horizontal">
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
</div>
```

Now what i want, is to give to every "grid grid-flex" 's child a unique class. That means that every "grid-item result-entry" should have an additional unique class. For example something like this:

```
<div class="grid grid-flex gutters-horizontal">
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry unique_1">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry unique_2">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry unique_3">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
</div>

<div class="grid grid-flex gutters-horizontal">
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry unique_1">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry unique_2">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
 <dl class="grid-item result-entry unique_3">
   <dd class="font-nowrap font-line">Foo</dd>
   <dt class="font-s onlyLarge">Foo</dt>
 </dl>
</div>
```

My code now looks like this:

```
$kaltMieteFinder = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$kaltMieteLists = $kaltMieteFinder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $findKaltMiete ')]");
$findingkaltMiete = new \DOMDocument(); 

foreach ($kaltMieteLists as $kaltMieteList) {
 $findingkaltMiete->appendChild($findingkaltMiete->importNode($kaltMieteList,true));
}
$mieteHTML.=trim($findingkaltMiete->saveHTML());
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($s);
$findKaltMiete = 'grid-flex';
$nextStep = 'grid-item';
$kaltMieteFinder = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$kaltMieteLists = $kaltMieteFinder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $findKaltMiete ')]");

foreach ($kaltMieteLists as $kaltMieteList) {
   // Start value for unique class
   $i = 1;
   // Select  child 'grid-item' tags
   $items = $kaltMieteFinder->query(".//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $nextStep ')]", $kaltMieteList);
   foreach($items as $x) {
     // append new class for existing value 
     $x->setAttribute('class',  $x->getAttribute('class') . ' unique' .$i++);
   }
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/922151)

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the XPath expression to find all of the class attributes which are the direct descendants of nodes with the class your after, you can then add the required text to the end of the node...

```
$kaltMieteFinder = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$kaltMieteLists = $kaltMieteFinder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'grid grid-flex')]/*/@class");

foreach ($kaltMieteLists as $key=>$kaltMieteList) {
    $kaltMieteList->value .=" unique_".($key+1);
}
```